# Getting the parameters out of uri

Tags: php, url, methods, controller, mapping

I setup a simple router class that extracts the following

1. Controller
2. Action
3. Parameters

class Router {

```
private $uri;
private $controller;
private $method;
private $params;

public function __construct($uri) {
    $this->uri = $uri;
    $this->method = 'index';
    $this->params = array();
}

public function map() {
    $uri = explode('/', $this->uri);
    if (empty($uri[0])) {
        $c = new Config('app');
        $this->controller = $c->default_controller;
    } else {
        if (!empty($uri[1]))
            $this->method = $uri[1];
        // how about the parameters??
    }
}
```

}

That simple `$router->map()` can give me the right controller, action and a single parameter from this uri `http://domain.com/users/edit/2`

That is quite okay, but what if I needed to store more parameters in the url like this :
`http://domain.com/controller/action/param/param2/param3`

How do I push them to `$parms` if I don't know how many parameters will be passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the 1st two values of array are **controller** and **action**, everything after will be a **param**.

So you could use `array_shift($uri)` to get the first 2 and the remaining `$uri` will be your params.

```
public function map() {
    $uri = explode('/', $this->uri);

    // shift element off beginning of array.

    $controller = array_shift($uri);
    $action = array_shift($uri);

    // your $uri variable will not only contain the params.

    if (empty($uri[0])) {
        $c = new Config('app');
        $this->controller = $c->default_controller;
    } else {
        if (!empty($uri[1]))
            $this->method = $uri[1];
        // how about the parameters??
    }
}
```

Comment: you shifted before knowing if `$uri[0]` is empty? would that be alright?

Comment: You could check if $uri[0] is empty then run your default controller code. It's your framework, I'll leave that decision to you.